# Auto Start Script

Tags: bash, rhel, erpnext

So I am making a script that can run these commands whenever a server boot/reboot:

```
sudo bash
su - erp
cd frappe-bench/
bench start >/tmp/bench_log &
```

I found guides here and there about how can I change user in script I came out with the following script:

```
#! /bin/sh

sudo -u erp bash
cd /home/erp/frappe-bench/
bench start >/tmp/bench_log &
```

And, I have created a service at `/etc/systemd/system/` and set it to run automatically when the server boots up.

The problem is, whenever I run `sudo systemctl start erpnextd.service` and checked the status, it came up with this

```
May 24 17:10:05 appbsystem2 systemd[1]: Started ERPNext | Auto Restart.
May 24 17:10:05 appbsystem2 sudo[18814]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=>erp ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
May 24 17:10:05 appbsystem2 systemd[1]: erpnextd.service: Succeeded.
```

But it still doesn't start up ERPNext.

All I wanted to do is make a script that will start erpnext automatically everytime a server reboot.

Note: I only install frappe-bench on user erp only

Comment: The `sudo -u erp bash` looks odd. This starts an interactive bash. My guess is that the command _bench start_ won't ever be executed. Did you try, just for testing, to run the script from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using systemd, you already have all the features from your script available, and better. So you don't even need the script anymore:

```
[Unit]
Description=...

[Service]

# Run as user erp.
User=erp
# You probably also want to run as group erp, if it exists.
Group=erp

# Change to this directory before executing.
WorkingDirectory=/home/erp/frappe-bench

# Redirect standard output to the given log file.
StandardOutput=file:/tmp/bench_log
# Redirect standard error to the same log file.
StandardError=file:/tmp/bench_log

# Command line for starting the program. Make sure to use an absolute path!
ExecStart=/full/path/to/bench start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. When executing your script, I encounter an error and I managed to solve it by adding the [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target. But your answer really helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Edited to add that. Systemd is pretty great once you wrap your head around it. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Using crontab (the script will start after every reboot/startup)

```
#crontab -e
@reboot sh /full/path/to/bench start >/tmp/bench_log
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provide by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360705/17434337) is very helpful.

However, I found another workaround by adding the path of my script file into the bottom of /etc/rc.local file.

Both method works, just a matter of preference ;)